# Programmatically restart or stop and start an application on Azure Web Sites

Tags: c#, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to restart/bounce my Azure Web site on a reserved instance ([Azure Web Sites](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/home/scenarios/web-sites/)) but I can't seem to find any documentation anywhere to do this.  I can do it via the new portal ([Azure Management Portal](https://manage.windowsazure.com)) but I want to do it via c# code.

Comment: Based on a recent thread (http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazurewebsitespreview/thread/f4e69962-a1ec-437f-b205-bb1664242ed2) it doesn't look like there's a public API at this stage - keep in mind Web Sites are still in a preview phase.

Comment: The Cross Platform Tools have the ability to do this, you could look at the bindings in Node to be able to make REST calls to the proper API. http://github.com/windowsazure/azure-sdk-for-node

Answer (score 2):

Check this sample, how to interact with Azure Management API: https://github.com/davidebbo/AzureWebsitesSamples/blob/master/ManagementLibrarySample/Program.cs

There is a `RestartAsync` method (`_websiteClient.WebSites.RestartAsync`) you can use to restart your website.

Comment: `Restart` ist there. Where is `Stop` and `Start` though?